# Make column default to NULL explicitly

Tags: sql, oracle, null, oracle-sqldeveloper, default-value

**How do I make a column default to NULL *explicitly*?**

I would like to declare a column in Oracle SQL Developer to be `NULL` on default. I'm aware of the fact, that `NULL` will be the default value, if I do not define any default value at all. But how do I define `NULL` as default, if I would want to do it explicitly?

```
-- 1: Does not work.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (
  MY_COLUMN TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT null
);

-- 2: Does not work.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (
  MY_COLUMN TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL
);

-- 3: Does not work.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (
  MY_COLUMN TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT (null)
);

-- 4: This works.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (
  MY_COLUMN TIMESTAMP(6)
);
```

In case 1-3 the default value will be a String ("`NULL`", "`null`" or "`(null)`"), but not an actual `NULL` value. So, what am I missing here?

**// Edit:**

Case (a) and (b) correspond to case 1 and 2. A text value of `null` or `NULL` is displayed in SQL Developer. Case (c) corresponds to case 4, where a *real* `(null)` value is set explicitly. The screenshots were taken on a table's *Columns* tab in SQL Developer.

[SQL Developer http://s1.postimg.org/fclraa0dp/SQL_Developer.png](http://s1.postimg.org/fclraa0dp/SQL_Developer.png)

Comment: Do you have any reason for wanting this other than to satisfy your own curiosity? (That's a valid reason, but other reasons might prompt other answers.)

Comment: Works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0113/1 there must be something else you are not telling us. What is the **exact** error message you get? (Btw: statement 1,2 and 3 are identical)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: There is no error, it simply puts no ``(null)`` value as default. You should read my question more carefully, I did mention that already. Also, why did you remove the ``oracle-sqldeveloper`` tag?

Comment: @hvd: Just curious how to put ``(null)`` as default value in query with SQL Developer (explicitly).

Comment: Because the SQL client being used is irrelevant for the question. And in the case 1-3 the default value will **not** be a string. It **will** be a `null` value. And what exactly do you mean with "*it simply puts no (null) value as default*" - where do you expect this null value to be "put"? Does it not show up in the DDL for the table? Does it no insert a null value when you run an insert?

Comment: Hmmm, a question about a default default. Well I guess that if the default default is null, then whether Oracle chooses to explicitly identify that or not is an internal matter. I think this is an example of a question in which it would help to know what problem, if any, a solution would help with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This question is tightly bound to SQL Developer, since that's were the ``null`` is handled differently in each query I posted. When I say *put*, I'm talking about the output in SQL Developer's *Columns* tab.

Comment: @user1438038 You understand that SQL Developer is just an interface to the Oracle RDBMS, and that SQL Developer itself does not have a default value for the column? It is just reading it from the database catalog. SQL Developer could be modified to make the word "NULL" appear as the default value for a column when no default has been set, but that is just a presentation issue that is entirely separate matter to what the default is in the database.

Comment: Not seeing your screenshot.

Comment: I suspect you have misunderstood the syntax. `'NULL'` is a string containing the characters `N`, `U`, `L`, `L`. `NULL` is not a string, it is an expression that evaluates to NULL; same as `null` and `(null)` and `(NULL)` which are all logically equivalent.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Then why is the input field empty when ``(null)`` was set implicitly or vice versa why does SQL Developer display ``(null)`` if the implicit default is *no value*. It just seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Probably because you're doing strange things - there's no logical reason to set the default to any of these expressions since `NULL` is the default anyway, so why anyone would care how SQL Developer displays it is beyond me.

Answer (score 7):

As `null`, `NULL` and `(null)` are the same thing, I don't understand what the problem is.

It is also not a SQL Developer "problem".

Oracle simply stores the default expression exactly as you wrote it in the system catalog. SQL Developer simply displays that.

Assume the following statements:

```
create table my_table (id integer);
alter table my_table add my_column_1 timestamp(6) default null;
alter table my_table add my_column_2 timestamp(6) default null;
alter table my_table add my_column_3 timestamp(6) default (null);
```

Then

```
select column_id, column_name, data_type, data_default
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
order by column_id;
```

Will return the following:

```
COLUMN_ID | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE    | DATA_DEFAULT
----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
        1 | ID          | NUMBER       |             
        2 | MY_COLUMN_1 | TIMESTAMP(6) | NULL        
        3 | MY_COLUMN_2 | TIMESTAMP(6) | null        
        4 | MY_COLUMN_3 | TIMESTAMP(6) | (null)
```

When you extract the DDL from the system, you again get exactly why you have written:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE', user)
from dual;
```

returns:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TK_HIRAC"."MY_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "MY_COLUMN_1" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    "MY_COLUMN_2" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT null, 
    "MY_COLUMN_3" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT (null)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

Comment: This behavior is indeed confusing. It leaves impression that the value was stored as a string literal null NULL or (null), even when it's actually legit NULL. I was scratching my head very long when I stumbled upon this issue thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HUSQVIK@panel_management> CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (C1 NUMBER NULL);
```

Table created.

```
HUSQVIK@panel_management> ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (
  2    MY_COLUMN TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL
  3  );
```

Table altered.

```
HUSQVIK@panel_management>
```

works for me.

Comment: This still makes the default `NULL` implicitly. The `NULL` here specifies that the column is nullable, not that the default value is `NULL`.

Comment: With your edit, that is one of the options the OP gives as something that does not work.

Comment: That's good, then. :) It probably means the OP is using some other version though. I'd normally request more specific info from the OP on the question in that case, but that's already been done.

Comment: This will put a default value of ``NULL``, but its simply text. Not ``(null)`` in the sense of *no value*. I'm on SQL Developer 4.0.1.14. What version are you using?

Comment: @user1438038 If you're typing NULL into a cell on SQL Developer that sets the default value for the column, then this is not the SQL that is being issued -- SQL Developer is setting  DEFAULT "NULL", not SQL.